# Get the last 5 posts in 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get the 5 last post (by date (created_at)) from replies + posts.

Example is better than explaination:

```
-- topics --
id  -  title  -  content  -  created_at
----------------------------------------
 1  -  title  -  content  -  2019-02-05 19:14:41
 2  -  title2 -  content2 -  2019-02-05 19:14:42
 3  -  title3 -  content3 -  2019-02-05 19:14:43
 4  -  title4 -  content4 -  2019-02-05 19:14:44
 5  -  title5 -  content5 -  2019-02-05 19:14:45

-- replies --
id  -  content  -  created_at
--------------------------
 1  -  content  -  2019-02-05 19:14:41
 2  -  content2 -  2019-02-05 19:14:42
 3  -  content3 -  2019-02-05 19:14:43
 4  -  content4 -  2019-02-05 19:14:44
 5  -  content5 -  2019-02-05 19:14:45
```

The result expected is:

```
OR 3 - title3 - content3 - 2019-02-05 19:14:43 
OR 3 - content3 - 2019-02-05 19:14:43 (doesn't matter)
4 - title4 - content4 - 2019-02-05 19:14:44
5 - title5 - content5 - 2019-02-05 19:14:45
4 - content4 - 2019-02-05 19:14:44
5 - content5 - 2019-02-05 19:14:45
```

I'm using MySQL

Comment: Note that "doesn't matter" is often symptomatic of poor design. It *should* matter!

Comment: You are right, I think this case is very rarely (I didn't thought to this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can union both queries that fetch all informations, order by date, then limit to 5 results

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE topics (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `title` VARCHAR(6),
  `content` VARCHAR(8),
  `created_at` DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO topics
  (`id`, `title`, `content`, `created_at`)
VALUES
  (1, 'title', 'content', '2019-02-05 19:14:41'),
  (2, 'title2', 'content2', '2019-02-05 19:14:42'),
  (3, 'title3', 'content3', '2019-02-05 19:14:43'),
  (4, 'title4', 'content4', '2019-02-05 19:14:44'),
  (5, 'title5', 'content5', '2019-02-05 19:14:45');

CREATE TABLE replies (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `content` VARCHAR(8),
  `created_at` DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO replies
  (`id`, `content`, `created_at`)
VALUES
  (1, 'content', '2019-02-05 19:14:41'),
  (2, 'content2', '2019-02-05 19:14:42'),
  (3, 'content3', '2019-02-05 19:14:43'),
  (4, 'content4', '2019-02-05 19:14:44'),
  (5, 'content5', '2019-02-05 19:14:45');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(title, ' - ', content) AS "title - content", created_at
FROM topics
UNION ALL
SELECT id, content, created_at
FROM replies
ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5;
```

**Output**

```
| id  | title - content   | created_at          |
| --- | ----------------- | ------------------- |
| 5   | title5 - content5 | 2019-02-05 19:14:45 |
| 5   | content5          | 2019-02-05 19:14:45 |
| 4   | content4          | 2019-02-05 19:14:44 |
| 4   | title4 - content4 | 2019-02-05 19:14:44 |
| 3   | content3          | 2019-02-05 19:14:43 |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
-- If you want to sort them by date ascending, you can nest the previous query into another one, that you sort by date ascending
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT id, CONCAT(title, ' - ', content) AS "title - content", created_at
    FROM topics
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, content, created_at
    FROM replies
    ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5
) subQuery
ORDER BY subQuery.created_at ASC;
```

**Output**

```
| id  | title - content   | created_at          |
| --- | ----------------- | ------------------- |
| 3   | content3          | 2019-02-05 19:14:43 |
| 4   | content4          | 2019-02-05 19:14:44 |
| 4   | title4 - content4 | 2019-02-05 19:14:44 |
| 5   | content5          | 2019-02-05 19:14:45 |
| 5   | title5 - content5 | 2019-02-05 19:14:45 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tFBx4ojESCqnw6eqeD2MLn/1)

Answer (score 1):

This should answer your question

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE topics (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `title` VARCHAR(6),
  `content` VARCHAR(8),
  `created_at` datetime
);

INSERT INTO topics
  (`id`, `title`, `content`, `created_at`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'title', 'content', '2019-02-05 19:14:41'),
  ('2', 'title2', 'content2', '2019-02-05 19:14:42'),
  ('3', 'title3', 'content3', '2019-02-05 19:14:43'),
  ('4', 'title4', 'content4', '2019-02-05 19:14:44'),
  ('5', 'title5', 'content5', '2019-02-05 19:14:45');

CREATE TABLE replies (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `content` VARCHAR(8),
  `created_at` datetime
);

INSERT INTO replies
  (`id`, `content`, `created_at`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'content', '2019-02-05 19:14:41'),
  ('2', 'content2', '2019-02-05 19:14:42'),
  ('3', 'content3', '2019-02-05 19:14:43'),
  ('4', 'content4', '2019-02-05 19:14:44'),
  ('5', 'content5', '2019-02-05 19:14:45');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select * from
(
 select * from topics
 union all 
 select id, null, content, created_at from replies
) t 
ORDER BY created_at desc
LIMIT 5;
```

**Result**

```
| id  | title  | content  | created_at          |
| --- | ------ | -------- | ------------------- |
| 5   |        | content5 | 2019-02-05 19:14:45 |
| 5   | title5 | content5 | 2019-02-05 19:14:45 |
| 4   |        | content4 | 2019-02-05 19:14:44 |
| 4   | title4 | content4 | 2019-02-05 19:14:44 |
| 3   |        | content3 | 2019-02-05 19:14:43 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n9ZRhqDJPQXP82MbhTnZwP/0)

Comment: Can you explain me the "null" value ? Edit, there isn't "from replies" ?

Comment: topics has title howerver replies don't. When we union them number of columns needs to match

Comment: yep I added it :)